# is there a way to rotate an actor's pitch past 90 degrees in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-blueprint

I a working on a game and for some reason I can't get my component to rotate past 90 degrees pitch.  I've distilled it down to EventTick->AddRelativeRotation(0, 5, 0) but when it hits the 90 degrees pitch mark it simply jitters back and fourth.  I've read many pages on this topic and I simply cannot find an answer.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug since 2014 but is not fixed yet. One way to get around this is make a rotator before then assign this rotator to target object.

1. Break old rotation into 3 float values
2. Make a new rotator adding the offset value from the old rotation (y=5 in your case)
3. Assign rotation to desired object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rotations using only three axes can be problematic. Rotations are more stable and reliable when using quaternions. The jittering you mention sounds a lot like something that would be fixed by using quaternion rotation instead.

It can be a bit confusing but there's plenty of documentation about this on the internet now that you have a term to search for.

Then, have a look at this UE forum post: [Rotate a mesh around its center using quaternion](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/rotate-a-mesh-around-its-center-using-quaternion/444575) It contains a link to a video showing how to do rotations using quaternions in UE, and some Blueprint that might help as well.